# Determining the limit as the denominator goes to zero

Tags: derivatives

[image]

It's been a while since I've taken an intro calculus class. Could someone remind me of this? I'm guessing it's La'Hopitals but a refresher would be super helpful

$
\lim_{\gamma\to1} \frac{c_{t}^{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma} = ln(C_t)
$

Comment: What you wrote diverges to +/- infinity

Comment: your equation is wrong, the nominator goes to 0 the denominator to 1 so the expression goes to infty

Comment: hmmmm let me attach an image of what is written in the book I'm looking at in the book. Maybe I'm looking at it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a misprint in the book. A power utility function should take the form

$$u(c_t) = \frac{c_t^{1-\gamma}-1}{1-\gamma}$$

Using L’Hopital’s rule for this $0/0$ indeterminate form, we have

$$\lim_{\gamma \to 1} u(c_t) = \lim_{\gamma \to 1}\frac{-\ln(c_t)e^{\ln(c_t)(1-\gamma)}}{-1} = \ln(c_t)$$

Comment: Also known as a CRRA or isoelastic utility function. See Wikipedia reference under isoelastic utility.

Comment: you're the man. Thank you

Comment: You’re very welcome.